# What does 8badf00d mean?

Tags: iphone, crash

Sometimes my iPhone application crashes with a weird crashlog, that reads exception code is 0x8badf00d. The stacktraces show random snapshots of app execution, but nothing suspicious. This happens very rarely and I'm not able to find out how to reproduce it. Does anybody know more about this kind of exception and exception code?

Here is an excerpt from my crashlogs:

> Exception Type:  00000020
>   Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
>   Highlighted Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   Failed to deactivate
>
> Thread 0:
>   ...
>   < nothing suspicious here >
>   ...
>
> Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Comment: Nobody has actually answered the question although they have all explanined the error code.

Could you let us know what you are doing to cause the exception.

Comment: how can we find which peace of code is problematic?

Comment: new apple doc for `8badf00d`, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`0x8badf00d` is the error code that the watchdog raises when an application takes too long to launch or terminate. See Apple's [Crash Reporting for iPhone OS Applications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html) document

Comment: Finally an answer to the question, thank you! I'll need to investigate more to confirm this is the actual reason for my crashlogs, but since you provide a link to an official source, I'll accept it.

Comment: Usually it means you either have an infinite loop somewhere, or you are waiting for network IO on the main thread. There's also the possibility that the user is force-quitting the application.

Comment: @rpetrich so for example my NSURLConnection coincide with renewing a background task. Do you think a 0x8badf00d can happen in this scenario? Because this is my theory.
BTW +1 for your answer.

Comment: @IBG It's certainly possible. I've never used those APIs.

Comment: Thanks. I confirmed that it was the case by testing it.

Comment: @IBG How did you test for it in your case?

Comment: @BradMoore sorry I completely forgot how I tested, as I wasn't working exclusively on that project (or any iOS project we have for that matter). I think what I did was reject the NSURLConnection part first, and then put it back again.

Comment: @IBG ah okay. I'll fish around and see what I can find.

Answer (score 16):

If you get `Exception Type: 00000020` and `Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d` then it is **watchdog timeout crash reports**. The exception code `0x8badf00d` is called `"ate bad food"`.

The most common `reason for this crash is synchronous activity on main thread.` The fix is to `switch to asynchronous activity` on main thread.

[image: Screenshot for Apple document]

[Refer this Apple document for more detail.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html)

Answer (score 8):

It is HexSpeak, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Comment: and may imply invalid parameters passed

Answer (score 5):

It's some programmer's idea of a joke.  You have to pick a number for your code, but the number doesn't necessarily mean anything in itself.  `8badf00d` is just another way to write the number 2,343,432,205, and was chosen because it looks 'funny' when represented in hex for an exception log.

Comment: I'd contend that it doesn't just "look" funny, but that it IS funny!  </subjectivity>  :-)

Answer (score 5):

`0x8badf00d exception` is raised by apple provided watchdog. The most common cause for watchdog timeout crashes in a network application is synchronous networking on the main thread. There are four contributing factors here:

> synchronous networking — This is where you make a network request and block waiting for the response.
>
> main thread — Synchronous networking is less than ideal in general, but it causes specific problems if you do it on the main thread. Remember that the main thread is responsible for running the user interface. If you block the main thread for any significant amount of time, the user interface becomes unacceptably unresponsive.
>
> long timeouts — If the network just goes away (for example, the user is on a train which goes into a tunnel), any pending network request won't fail until some timeout has expired. Most network timeouts are measured in minutes, meaning that a blocked synchronous network request on the main thread can keep the user interface unresponsive for minutes at a time.
>
> Trying to avoid this problem by reducing the network timeout is not a good idea. In some situations it can take many seconds for a network request to succeed, and if you always time out early then you'll never make any progress at all.
>
> watchdog — In order to keep the user interface responsive, iOS includes a watchdog mechanism. If your application fails to respond to certain user interface events (launch, suspend, resume, terminate) in time, the watchdog will kill your application and generate a watchdog timeout crash report. The amount of time the watchdog gives you is not formally documented, but it's always less than a network timeout.

There are two common solutions:

> asynchronous networking — The best solution to this problem is to run your networking code asynchronously. Asynchronous networking code has a number of advantages, not least of which is that it lets you access the network safely without having to worry about threads.
>
> synchronous networking on a secondary thread — If it's prohibitively difficult to run your networking code asynchronously (perhaps you're working with a large portable code base that assumes synchronous networking), you can avoid the watchdog by running your synchronous code on a secondary thread.

Refer apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1693/_index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's a failure code added by a dev with a good sense of humor.  Because hexadecimal uses letters as well as numbers, it's possible to come up with hex numbers that look approximately like english words, such as "0xdeadbeef", etc.  I'm sure that the exception has a specific meaning, but if there's no major symptoms associated with it, you can probably ignore it without too much concern.

Answer (score -7):

from wikipedia 0xBAADF00D ("bad food") is used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to indicate uninitialised allocated heap memory when the debug heap is used.[7]

Comment: Where does Microsoft's LocalAlloc comes into picture here?