# iPhone: Unusual crashing on app loading occurs only on ios4

Tags: iphone

One of our games "iCopter Classic", which was once in the top selling list and has 100K unique users everyday, is getting bad comments from frustrated users.

The problem they keep reporting is, "The app, crashes on launch" on many ios4 devices, irrespective of the hardware they run on. We have tested the game on iPod Touch 2g, 3g, iPhone 2g, 3gs, 4 and with many iOS combinations. But we were not able to reproduce the problem.

Our download count went down to 50% because of this problem and bad comments for past 3 updates. We fixed all iOS 4 related code and now clueless of what to do next to fix this issue.

We somehow got crash reports from one of the users which we are not sure how to point the bug.

**NOTE**: My doubt is on this part of the code. We are loading around 200 images with separate uiimage objects for loading flags of countries.

Crash log says:

```
Exception Type: 00000020     
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
```

Comment: Again with the bad food.

Comment: This is a dup, sorry to say, but your answer has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282491/i-get-error-0x8badf00d-in-iphone-app-and-is-not-the-usual-suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to chase up is the log file from the user, that will give you some useful information on what is going on.

You can *symbolicate* the crash log from your user (and get a readable call stack), by running the *symbolicatecrash* utility with the exact .dSYM that was generated when the application was first built:

> symbolicatecrash -o   .app.dSYM

SymbolicateCrash usually lives in:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Comment: Checked everything. But there is no clue to find which line gives this problem... Problem is not reproducible in our devices. :(

Comment: @Cannonade yes, I did from one user. The crash is due to launch timeout. so its on different lines every time. But it doesn't reflect on our devices.

Comment: @codetiger I assume you have tried an AdHoc build on your device? Is there network interaction that might cause different timing to expose a otherwise hidden fault?

Comment: @connondae 
Yes, there is a network activity of just posting an int. which we have now removed and sending that for new update. However, we have moved all initializations to other functions and the didfinishlaunching function will just do nothing now. LEts hope it works fine now.