# iOS : Application Crashes with error "Application failed to launch in time"

Tags: ios

My iOS app doesn't run in background. When home button is hit the app will terminate.

Below is my code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
  double sleepTime = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] - 1;

  [self performTaskforTime:sleepTime];
}
```

If the application is relaunched in no time, the New instance of the app will killed with the error :

> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d Highlighted
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: My_App failed to launch in time

I can't reduce the sleep time. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return from `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`, do something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier btid = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

  double sleepTime = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] - 1;

  dispatch_async(/* background queue */, ^{
    [self performTaskforTime:sleepTime];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:btid];
  }
}
```

You don't want to block the main queue with a long running task as you won't be able to service the UI otherwise. Your application is busy with `-performTaskforTime:` and thus can't launch in time.

Comment: I tried this, since my app doesnt run in background will quit and the task will be never performed.

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to call -beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block the main application thread for more than a few seconds. See this SO post.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282491/i-get-error-0x8badf00d-in-iphone-app-and-is-not-the-usual-suspect)

Comment: I see the app is launched as a new instance, and in the new instance the thread is not blocked.