# app quits on launch

Tags: iphone

I just posted an update of my app to AppStore. It was approved by Apple. It has been tested on 2 iphone devices (3G - 3GS with 3.1.2). It worked fine but when downloaded from AppStore it doesn't launch, just displayed the default screen and returned to iphone menu. I have no idea where to look. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There can be problems associated with the download of apps.

Read Apples own [trouble shooting guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1702).

Comment: All the reboot, sync, deauthorize, reauthorize, desinstall have been done.... Many of my users have this issue. I had the same as them when I bought my app from AppStore.

Comment: A common mistake can be to do to much data loading or processing in the main thread during startup. The app should get back to its event handling within a few seconds or the OS will kill it without any mercy.

Comment: If you can view a crashreport you can look for "Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d" ---- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean

Answer (score 1):

Hook up your device to a machine running XCode, then view the Crash Logs in the Organizer.