# App Crash on launch iOS 7 Crash log explain

Tags: ios, crash, ios7, launch

I couldn't understand where is my problem. My apps crash on launch with this crash log.

> iOS 7.0.2 (11A501) Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
>   Highlighted Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: com.myapps failed
>   to launch in time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.420 (user 4.420, system 0.000),
>   10% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.714, 2% CPU
>
> Thread 0: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878ead4
>   semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x386dbdec
>   _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 172 2   CFNetwork                         0x2dabab16 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 266 3   Foundation
>     0x2e883a4e +[NSURLConnection
>   sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 110 4   Foundation 
>     0x2e8d8c80 -[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:] + 188 5 
>   QuizPatente!                      0x0004d980 0x3e000 + 63872 6
>   QuizPatente!                      0x00048820 0x3e000 + 43040 7
>   QuizPatente!                      0x00048644 0x3e000 + 42564 8   UIKit
>     0x306fc020 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 376 9
>   UIKit                             0x306e762c -[UIApplication
>   _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 1092 10  UIKit                           0x30681be2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3138 11  UIKit
>     0x30680ed8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68 12  UIKit
>     0x306e6c9c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 660 13  GraphicsServices
>     0x32b6276a _PurpleEventCallback + 606 14  GraphicsServices
>     0x32b62352 PurpleEventCallback + 30 15  CoreFoundation
>     0x2dec177c **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 32 16  CoreFoundation                   0x2dec1716 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342 17  CoreFoundation                    0x2debfee2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1402 18  CoreFoundation
>     0x2de2a53c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 19  CoreFoundation
>     0x2de2a31e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102 20  UIKit
>     0x306e5f3e -[UIApplication _run] + 758 21  UIKit
>     0x306e11e0 UIApplicationMain + 1132 22  QuizPatente!
>     0x00045a28 0x3e000 + 31272 23  libdyld.dylib
>     0x386eaab4 start + 0
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878e838 kevent64 + 24
>   1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x386dd0d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke +
>   228 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x386d763e _dispatch_mgr_thread
>   + 34
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878ead4
>   semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x386dbf90
>   _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 168 2   GameCenterFoundation              0x2ea86dc4 __35-[GKDaemonProxy buildServiceLookup]_block_invoke + 628
>   3   libdispatch.dylib                 0x386d6100
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8 4   libdispatch.dylib                0x386dae72 _dispatch_queue_drain + 370 5   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x386d7f96 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 38 6   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x386db74e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74 7   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x386db9cc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x38805dfc _pthread_wqthread + 296 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38805cc0 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x387a1c7c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38805e06 _pthread_wqthread + 306 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x38805cc0 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x387a1c7c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38805e06 _pthread_wqthread + 306 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x38805cc0 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x387a0f38
>   **psynch_cvwait + 24 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x38807262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3880803c pthread_cond_wait + 36 3   Foundation                        0x2e86574a
>   -[NSCondition wait] + 190 4   QuizPatente!                    0x0026c5b0 0x3e000 + 2287024 5   Foundation
>
>     0x2e8dadc2 _*NSThread*_main** + 1058 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807c5a _pthread_body + 138 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807bca _pthread_start + 98 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38805ccc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878ea84 mach_msg_trap
>   + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3878e87c mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2dec155c **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
>   152 3   CoreFoundation                    0x2debfc7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
>   4   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a53c CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   520 5   CoreFoundation                    0x2de6e1a6 CFRunLoopRun + 94 6 
>   QuizPatente!                      0x001ec3b4 0x3e000 + 1762228 7
>
>   Foundation                        0x2e8dadc2 _*NSThread*_main** + 1058 8 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x38807c5a _pthread_body + 138 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x38807bca _pthread_start + 98 10 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x38805ccc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 7: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3878ea84 mach_msg_trap + 20 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3878e87c mach_msg + 36 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x2dec155c **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
>   152 3   CoreFoundation                    0x2debfc7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
>   4   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a53c CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   520 5   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a31e CFRunLoopRunInMode +
>   102 6   Foundation                        0x2e86564c
>   +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316 7   Foundation                        0x2e8dadc2 _*NSThread*_main** + 1058 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807c5a _pthread_body + 138 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807bca _pthread_start + 98 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38805ccc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878ea84 mach_msg_trap
>   + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3878e87c mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2dec155c **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
>   152 3   CoreFoundation                    0x2debfc7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
>   4   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a53c CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   520 5   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a31e CFRunLoopRunInMode +
>   102 6   Foundation                        0x2e818822
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250 7   Foundation                      0x2e869664 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76 8   QuizPatente!
>
>     0x000e9fd4 0x3e000 + 704468 9   Foundation
>
>     0x2e8dadc2 _*NSThread*_main** + 1058 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807c5a _pthread_body + 138 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38807bca _pthread_start + 98 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x38805ccc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 9: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3878ea84 mach_msg_trap
>   + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3878e87c mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2dec155c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
>   152 3   CoreFoundation                    0x2debfc7c _*CFRunLoopRun + 788
>   4   CoreFoundation                    0x2de2a53c CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   520 5   CoreFoundation                    0x2de6e1a6 CFRunLoopRun + 94 6 
>   CoreMotion                        0x2e4e2394
>   _*_lldb_unnamed_function1407$$CoreMotion + 724 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38807c5a _pthread_body + 138 8
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x38807bca _pthread_start + 98 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x38805ccc thread_start + 4

I update my app today. The strange behavior has come only when the app is updated. If users reinstall the app it work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 8badf00d mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean)

Comment: If you symbolicate the file, then we'll have some better clues with these lines that are related to your app. 
QuizPatente! 0x00048820 0x3e000 + 43040 7
QuizPatente! 0x00048644 0x3e000 + 42564 8 UIKit

Answer (score 6):

Based on:

> Application Specific Information: com.myapps failed to launch in time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.420 (user 4.420, system 0.000),
>   10% CPU Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.714, 2% CPU

it looks like your app is not returning from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in time.

You are probably doing something in that method that is blocking the thread and preventing it from returning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've moved out of application:didFinishLaunching: a method that copy a database file. Is possible that a simple procedure like copy a file (just a 4K) could block the launching of app?

Comment: Maybe on some devices the database file has become very large.

Comment: In any case, that sort of operation is definitely not something that you should do in applicationDidFinishLaunching. You should only do the most basic initialization there and return as quickly as possible.

Comment: Ok, I removed anything from my applicationDidFinishLaunching but still crash.

Comment: The only things that now are in that method is :[Parse setApplicationId:@"" clientKey:@""];
    [InMobi initialize:@""];
    [Flurry startSession:@""];

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try eliminating those one by one. It's hard to know what 3rd party libraries are doing. It's possible one of them is buggy or hasn't been updated for iOS 7. Hopefully they're smart enough to spawn new threads for their blocking processes, but maybe they're not.