# How resolve this crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I run my application on iOS 8.2. The application is running and execute my code well, on one of my tested devices it is crashed. how can i fix it? why it is crash on specific device?

i need a help with my crash report that is re-sybolized from xcode:

**UPDATE**

```
  Incident Identifier: BCFDF373-FBBB-426E-815A-E505815A242D
CrashReporter Key:   7bdf0f8901538029d4ad24b28464939238c4b283
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             LEAF_v2 [2488]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/35BAE7D4-0ED6-4D78-9B4B-442833576306/LEAF_v2.app/LEAF_v2
Identifier:          com.SDS.LEAF-v2
Version:             1.0.150329 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-03-29 15:10:05.653 +0300
Launch Time:         2015-03-29 15:03:30.719 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.2 (12D508)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  8

Application Specific Information:
com.SDS.LEAF-v2 failed to scene-update in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.080 (user 4.080, system 0.000), 20% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.006, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394438b6 look_up_class + 106
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b628a62 CFRelease + 1158
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e9510 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 200
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e7cd6 __CFRunLoopRun + 782
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2b634b4c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2b63495e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
8   GraphicsServices                0x32b9a1a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
9   UIKit                           0x2ec86c8c UIApplicationMain + 1436
10  LEAF_v2                         0x000712fc 0x6b000 + 25340
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x399eaaac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a9d24c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00940bf4 0x932000 + 60404
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00934c8e 0x932000 + 11406

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.frontboardservices.workspace.client
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0d1c __psynch_rw_wrlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3ae _pthread_rwlock_lock + 338
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39449922 objc_duplicateClass + 106
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b728cd4 -[NSObject(NSObject) __dealloc_zombie] + 84
4   FrontBoardServices              0x31fe51bc -[FBSWorkspaceSceneEvent dealloc] + 68
5   FrontBoardServices              0x31fe52d0 -[FBSWorkspaceSceneUpdateResponseEvent dealloc] + 68
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3945bd52 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 162
7   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x39a05ad8 _Block_release + 216
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0093bd84 0x932000 + 40324
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00935ac0 0x932000 + 15040
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093db18 0x932000 + 47896
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093ee1c 0x932000 + 52764
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2dda6 _pthread_wqthread + 666
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2daf8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a9d4ec semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0093f03a 0x932000 + 53306
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2d13ab56 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1962
3   CoreMedia                       0x2be90bb4 figThreadMain + 184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fde8 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fd5a _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2db04 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394438b6 look_up_class + 106
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b628a62 CFRelease + 1158
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e720e __CFFinalizeRunLoop + 222
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e1262 __CFTSDFinalize + 66
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2ea94 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e7ce _pthread_exit + 82
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2de28 _pthread_wqthread + 796
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2daf8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394438b6 look_up_class + 106
3   CFNetwork                       0x2b180b94 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 16
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6345be CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
5   CFNetwork                       0x2b180a76 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 178
6   CFNetwork                       0x2b18093e MultiplexerSource::perform() + 214
7   CFNetwork                       0x2b1807d8 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 44
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6ea234 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e9646 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e7cc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2b634b4c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2b63495e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
13  CFNetwork                       0x2b1e8722 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
14  Foundation                      0x2c45d4b6 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fde8 _pthread_body + 136
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fd5a _pthread_start + 114
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2db04 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394438b6 look_up_class + 106
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b628a62 CFRelease + 1158
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6eea78 __CFSocketManager + 3296
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fde8 _pthread_body + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2fd5a _pthread_start + 114
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2db04 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394438b6 look_up_class + 106
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b628a62 CFRelease + 1158
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e720e __CFFinalizeRunLoop + 222
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b6e1262 __CFTSDFinalize + 66
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2ea94 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e7ce _pthread_exit + 82
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2de28 _pthread_wqthread + 796
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2daf8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x14727110.events
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a9d504 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0093effa 0x932000 + 53242
2   CoreLocation                    0x2bddad9a 0x2bdd8000 + 11674
3   CoreLocation                    0x2bde06f4 0x2bdd8000 + 34548
4   CoreLocation                    0x2be12ff2 0x2bdd8000 + 241650
5   CoreLocation                    0x2be11ff6 0x2bdd8000 + 237558
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x39b45816 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 38
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x39b48392 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 118
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x39b482f4 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 60
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x39b48292 notify_server + 62
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x39b43e50 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1528
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093608e 0x932000 + 16526
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093b91c 0x932000 + 39196
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00935788 0x932000 + 14216
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093b91c 0x932000 + 39196
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00935ac0 0x932000 + 15040
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093b91c 0x932000 + 39196
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00935ac0 0x932000 + 15040
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093db18 0x932000 + 47896
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093ee1c 0x932000 + 52764
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2dda6 _pthread_wqthread + 666
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2daf8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.networking.connection.0x15915300
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ab0c44 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2e3a0 _pthread_rwlock_lock + 324
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394480ce lookUpImpOrForward + 390
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39447f3a _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 30
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3944e1f6 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 22
5   libsystem_network.dylib         0x39aed45e tcp_connection_event_notify + 462
6   libsystem_network.dylib         0x39af718a __tcp_connection_init_skt_event_source_block_invoke + 166
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0094606e 0x932000 + 82030
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00934d68 0x932000 + 11624
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0093b91c 0x932000 + 39196
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00935ac0 0x932000 + 15040
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093db18 0x932000 + 47896
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0093ee1c 0x932000 + 52764
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2dda6 _pthread_wqthread + 666
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b2daf8 start_wqthread + 4

No thread state (register information) available
Binary Images:
```

Comment: You'll need to translate those symbols using the .dSYM file that was created when you built this app.

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/779387/2708650) in the meantime.

Comment: Where in the code is it crashing? If you add an exception breakpoint it will point out the line of code that is causing crash.

Comment: how parse from .dSYM? Ihave an ipa file

Comment: How to symbolicate iOS crash reports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports -- yours is only half-symbolicated (Apple's framework symbols are there, but your app's are missing).

Comment: See [Symbolicating Your iOS Crash Reports](http://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess:

"com.SDS.LEAF-v2 failed to exit in time"

... with the information given I can only conclude that it crashes on your slower device (which is an iPhone4,1), and it doesn't crash on your primary device which may be faster.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:1.0];

maybe this is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log which you added above given below are my assumptions

> 13  UIKit                           0x2ecd0c9c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 172

It seems that the crash is caused when you are performing some transitions from one view controller to the other, please check the navigation controller for this and add break points when you being the transitions.

> Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
>
> Application Specific Information:
> com.SDS.LEAF-v2 failed to exit in time

this looks like your application is causing issues in **iPhone model 4S** ([here's the list if you want to have a look](http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html)) and the other specific information looks like you application name.

To know more on what the crash is all about I would recommend [symbolicating your crash reports](http://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/)

Don't jump to conclusions if the application is working fine on other devices then do check for a workaround for iPhone 4S.

Comment: @user3428151: can you do the symbolication thing as mentioned in my answer, also did you try applying breakpoint, like when does the crash happen does it happen everytime when you tap on a button or its just some random crash that happens anytime. Another suggestion is to use crashlytics to get a detailed overview on whats actually going on

Comment: @user3428151another thought by looking at the log is you might be carring out some corelocation and NSURLConnection operation due to which this is happening not really sure though