# App crash EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know why this crash happens.

I set a GCD timer, when my app is in the background, and when time comes, it will crash like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f9f5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f9f4ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001909f25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001909f01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019091e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001923d2198 GSEventRunModal + 180
6   UIKit                           0x00000001969657fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
7   UIKit                           0x0000000196960534 UIApplicationMain + 208
8   WenWenJewel                     0x00000001002310ac 0x10006c000 + 1855660
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018f9015b8 start + 4
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Andreas I want to know why it happen.

Comment: Don't have access to Xcode atm, but interesting behavior. Maybe this sheds some light on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean

Comment: Perhaps the timer keeps your app alive until the watchdog kills it?

Comment: @Andreas Is there anyway to keep app alive even it's in the background for a very long time?

Comment: There are official use cases that allow it. No other way.

Comment: did you solve the issue  @CoderZyc.