# iOS App Crashed with Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Tags: ios, swift, crash

App is running fine on device, but when we submitted app to review it gets rejected multiple times. Unable to find reason. Here is the reason specified for crash.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog 
transgression: **bundle id** exhausted real (wall clock) time 
allowance of 18.32 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | 
ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | 
WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed 
total CPU time (seconds): 58.590 (user 58.590, system 0.000), 98% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 2.587, 4% CPU" | )
```

Here is thread Crash Report :

```
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194807ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019480737c mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019466c2d0 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 500
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019466c764 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$mp + 56
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001948cfea0 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 204
5   Security                        0x0000000195922aac securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 96
6   Security                        0x0000000195923070 securityd_send_sync_and_do + 80
7   Security                        0x000000019597c188 __SecItemDelete_block_invoke_2 + 248
8   Security                        0x000000019597b8c4 __SecItemAuthDoQuery_block_invoke + 312
9   Security                        0x000000019597a314 SecItemAuthDo + 108
10  Security                        0x000000019597abac SecItemAuthDoQuery + 512
11  Security                        0x0000000195978920 SecOSStatusWith + 52
12  Security                        0x000000019597b1a4 SecItemDelete + 448
13  MyApp                       0x0000000100cba760 0x100948000 + 3614560
```

I am not using any synchronous call at the time of launch. I have tried many solutions which was already mentioned in stackoverflow but still unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: have you implemented firebase crashlytics?

Comment: @AmirKhan yes its not recording any crashes.

Comment: Have Apple mentioned their iOS version and device name?

Comment: Check this post related to your crash log - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88529

Comment: @AmirKhan they have specified only iOS version : iPhone OS 12.1.4

Comment: you may have any background task and somehow that cause the crash. Check the link above, I mentioned. Hopefully you can resolve that issue.

Comment: That's a needle in a hay stack for those who know nothing about your app.  You don't even tell the main feature of your app.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the crash is that your application used up too much time in the background or took too long to launch and was therefore terminated by the watchdog process. This can be seen from the Termination Reason code. For more information, refer to this post: [What does 8badf00d mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean)

You have to figure out what causes the delay and resolve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 12.2 In my case

1. I set Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only for Release - yes

[image]

2. Check the Edit Scheme / Archive! Set to Release, not Run

[image]