# EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD

Tags: ios

Getting this crash and I'm unable to find the root cause

> Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

```
{"app_name":"Zeus","app_cohort":"2|date=1575473400000&sf=143465&tid=0b25cf8bf3b0b789b1344a52acaf37febe38ef02d00992e624398dc35995709c&ttype=i","app_version":"2.6.0","timestamp":"2019-12-05 22:09:27.15 +0800","slice_uuid":"f7f8cac0-74dd-36a8-9024-b5b4ef6483d4","adam_id":1280245865,"build_version":"20191203.1717","bundleID":"org.geekbang.GeekTime","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)","incident_id":"8DBD8388-D2E4-4026-905F-D26FD59D1A3C","is_beta":true,"name":"Zeus"}
```

```
Incident Identifier: 8DBD8388-D2E4-4026-905F-D26FD59D1A3C
Beta Identifier:     EA152B2B-875B-45CD-839E-3EC261D63815
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             Zeus [16757]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6A45E661-28E7-4CFA-8C5B-BA2CA8C1534C/Zeus.app/Zeus
Identifier:          org.geekbang.GeekTime
Version:             20191203.1717 (2.6.0)
AppStoreTools:       11B48b
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.geekbang.GeekTime [2471]


Date/Time:           2019-12-05 22:09:26.3229 +0800
Launch Time:         2019-12-05 09:48:40.1323 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.01.08
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog transgression: application<org.geekbang.GeekTime>:16757 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.570 (user 13.570, system 0.000), 21% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.587, 1% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

[image]

Comment: Frank I tried to edit your post and made as much as readable as possible. I saw that you're new, but try to understand that if you're not explaining your problem correctly nobody will be interested in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The termination reason (code) 0x8badf00d indicates that the application was terminated by the watchdog process of the operating system. This usually happens if the app (a) uses too much time in the background, or (b) needs too long to launch. Please refer to this answer [What does 8badf00d mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think the reason might be because of a bad splash screen. Try to see how many threads of SPRINGBOARD are running on your device by going to Xcode menu: debug-> attach to process