# React Native app rejected on AppStore, apparently fails on launch

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm about to publish my first ever app on the AppStore, but am facing some issues. A few days ago, my first build was rejected because it crashed on launch. However, I have been unable to reproduce it using AdHoc distribution and installing it on my phone as well as my co-founder's phone. I have also tried building it for multiple simulators - in none of those cases is it failing.

I symbolicated the crash report Apple gave me and here is the relevant part (only including the thread that crashed)

```
{

"app_name":"sigma","timestamp":"2020-08-25 07:32:34.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"274325c4-35dc-3c9a-aa82-98cda4a16a9b","adam_id":1526060121,"build_version":"2","bundleID":"com.sofyapp.sigma","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.6 (17G68)","incident_id":"B5275F1D-CA2D-4E30-ACED-E0AE5F4C4B0C","name":"sigma"}
Incident Identifier: B5275F1D-CA2D-4E30-ACED-E0AE5F4C4B0C
CrashReporter Key:   36178cb8e6da68c433c46e20bf698fff77381bd8
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             sigma [279]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7213F44D-8F36-437F-A032-822ABBBAA828/sigma.app/sigma
Identifier:          com.sofyapp.sigma
Version:             2 (1.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       11E707
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.sofyapp.sigma [445]


Date/Time:           2020-08-25 07:32:33.3465 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-08-25 07:32:13.2548 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.6 (17G68)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.07.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: application<com.sofyapp.sigma>:279 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.62 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.400 (user 6.400, system 0.000), 5% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.567, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b909e7c0 0x1b909a000 + 18368
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b8f7baf0 0x1b8f78000 + 15088
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b8f7c188 0x1b8f78000 + 16776
3   sigma                           0x000000010453d984 -[RCTBundleURLProvider isPackagerRunning:] + 4643204 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:96)
4   sigma                           0x000000010453e004 -[RCTBundleURLProvider guessPackagerHost] + 4644868 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:111)
5   sigma                           0x000000010453e220 -[RCTBundleURLProvider packagerServerHost] + 4645408 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:125)
6   sigma                           0x000000010453e318 -[RCTBundleURLProvider jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:fallbackExtension:] + 4645656 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:135)
7   sigma                           0x000000010453e4b8 -[RCTBundleURLProvider jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:] + 4646072 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:148)
8   sigma                           0x00000001040d6e70 -[AppDelegate sourceURLForBridge:] + 28272 (AppDelegate.m:91)
9   sigma                           0x000000010453c38c -[RCTBridge setUp] + 4637580 (RCTBridge.m:343)
10  sigma                           0x000000010453b7bc -[RCTBridge initWithDelegate:bundleURL:moduleProvider:launchOptions:] + 4634556 (RCTBridge.m:226)
11  sigma                           0x000000010453b4e0 -[RCTBridge initWithDelegate:launchOptions:] + 4633824 (RCTBridge.m:197)
12  sigma                           0x00000001040d6a38 -[AppDelegate initializeReactNativeApp] + 27192 (AppDelegate.m:62)
13  sigma                           0x00000001040d68f8 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 26872 (AppDelegate.m:44)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd3f7ddc 0x1bc993000 + 10898908
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd3f9bbc 0x1bc993000 + 10906556
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd3ff588 0x1bc993000 + 10929544
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb6fd60 0x1bc993000 + 1953120
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd03b588 0x1bc993000 + 6981000
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb70894 0x1bc993000 + 1955988
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb702c0 0x1bc993000 + 1954496
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb706b0 0x1bc993000 + 1955504
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb6ff38 0x1bc993000 + 1953592
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb74654 0x1bc993000 + 1971796
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcf59f8c 0x1bc993000 + 6057868
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd05522c 0x1bc993000 + 7086636
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb74390 0x1bc993000 + 1971088
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd055114 0x1bc993000 + 7086356
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcb741e8 0x1bc993000 + 1970664
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bc9da918 0x1bc993000 + 293144
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bc9d9418 0x1bc993000 + 287768
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bc9da648 0x1bc993000 + 292424
32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd3fd828 0x1bc993000 + 10922024
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bcf80780 0x1bc993000 + 6215552
34  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be51c084 0x1be50f000 + 53380
35  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be542610 0x1be50f000 + 210448
36  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be526f40 0x1be50f000 + 98112
37  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be5422a4 0x1be50f000 + 209572
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b8f7b5ac 0x1b8f78000 + 13740
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b8f7e33c 0x1b8f78000 + 25404
40  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be5686c8 0x1be50f000 + 366280
41  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be568374 0x1be50f000 + 365428
42  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001be5688e0 0x1be50f000 + 366816
43  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b9254d14 0x1b91a8000 + 707860
44  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b9254c68 0x1b91a8000 + 707688
45  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b92543c4 0x1b91a8000 + 705476
46  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b924f1fc 0x1b91a8000 + 684540
47  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b924ebc8 0x1b91a8000 + 682952
48  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c36305cc 0x1c362d000 + 13772
49  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bd401744 0x1bc993000 + 10938180
50  sigma                           0x00000001040d71b4 main + 29108 (main.m:14)
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b90cb384 0x1b90ca000 + 4996
```

I'm really not sure what to do here - can't fix the error until I fix it. I saw some similar issues on searching on Google but they had a line regarding Facebook library in the crash report so they were able to isolate the error. In my case, I don't see where the issue is happening either.

An important thing to note here is that my app has been exported from Expo.

Comment: How did you install the App on an Iphone? did you build the ios bundle and then how did you manage to get it on his Iphone? isnt that like impossible with Iphone and only doable threw the appstore?

Comment: you can use itunes for internal testing, remove old application before installing new one and if you are using any login system, use completely new accounts, it will increase the chances of catching the crash

Answer (score 1):

**ALWAYS a NO NO** to publish app that tested only with simulator. Suggest you to utilize TestFlight as a pre-production platform to test your application, as it provides you an environment close to real environment.

Here's [reason why our app is crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779387/4311268). Check again what's running in your `AppDelegate.m` that slowing your app to boot up.