# React Native Firebase Push Notification Crash Report Problem

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building an app with React Native. With React Native Firebase, I am adding push notification functionality. When I open a push notification from quit state, the app opens and hangs at the splash screen for a while, and then crashes.

Here is the crash report from the device, symbolicated. Honestly, I am new to programming and so I am having trouble in interpreting below report. I assume that there is a problem with RNSplashScreen module or AppDelegate.m, but can't be sure.

Can anyone help me out in interpreting this and point me to what might be a root cause/where to look at?

Thanks!

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
    Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<myapp.myapp>:2661 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 59.91 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 16.580 (user 16.580, system 0.000), 5% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.918, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001daebe2d0 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001daebd660 mach_msg + 76
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf08c30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf02c14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf0221c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    5   Foundation                      0x00000001ae1b1df0 -[NSRunLoop+ 36336 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
    6   Foundation                      0x00000001ae1b1cbc -[NSRunLoop+ 36028 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
    7   myapp                           0x00000001005d15f0 +[RNSplashScreen show] (in myapp) (RNSplashScreen.m:31) + 5641712
    8   myapp                           0x0000000100075be4 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (in myapp) (AppDelegate.m:53) + 23524
    9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001af93f228 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 360
    10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af941290 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 5136
    11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af946cec -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1244
    12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aef9cc74 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152
    13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af50af9c _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
    14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aef9d80c __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 224
    15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aef9d2cc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 484
    16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aef9d61c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768
    17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aef9ce58 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340
    18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aefa53a4 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 196
    19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af41760c +[BSAnimationSettings+ 6936076 (UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892
    20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af5236c4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 272
    21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aefa509c -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384
    22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aedcc5a0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 776
    23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aedcaf14 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256
    24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aedcc1c8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 248
    25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af944e8c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 572
    26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af440e38 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388
    27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bccf83bc -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
    28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd23d04 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.200 + 128
    29  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd074a0 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240
    30  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd239c8 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372
    31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001acb81db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001acb85738 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268
    33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd4c250 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
    34  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd4bee0 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448
    35  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001bcd4c434 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32
    36  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf0976c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    37  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf09668 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
    38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf08960 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
    39  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf02a8c __CFRunLoopRun + 824
    40  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acf0221c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    41  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c4ace784 GSEventRunModal + 164
    42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af942ee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
    43  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af94875c UIApplicationMain + 168
    44  myapp                       0x0000000100075db4 main (in myapp) (main.m:7) + 23988
    45  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001acbc26b0 start + 4
```

Comment: The termination reason has some critical, if cryptic information. Take a look at this question, it should help clarify a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean#779387

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after adding React Native Firebase to my project and found the answer in this issue: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/397

The real cause is in the react-native-splash-screen. Firebase requires to change "Background modes" in your App's Capabilities, this causes react-native-splash-screen to go into loop in RNSplashScreen.m:

```
while (waiting) {
    NSDate* later = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:later];
}
```

You can find it in this part of the backtrace:

```
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ae1b1df0 -[NSRunLoop+ 36336 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ae1b1cbc -[NSRunLoop+ 36028 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   myapp                           0x00000001005d15f0 +[RNSplashScreen show] (in myapp) (RNSplashScreen.m:31) + 5641712
```

To solve the problem you need to modify your AppDelegate.m, replace

```
[RNSplashScreen show]
```

with

```
[RNSplashScreen showSplash:@"LaunchScreen" inRootView:rootView];
```

But be careful, if your project uses LaunchScreen.storyboard instead of LaunchScreen.xib, you can catch this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D22A78C5-5733-4511-85BF-217A3BAEB6AB/myapp.app> (loaded)' with name 'LaunchScreen''

In this case you need to create the new View named "LaunchScreen" and copy-paste here your launch view from the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Comment: Great answer, saved the day for me, this should be a selected answer with 100s of upvotes, great job