# App Crash logs says its due to watch dog, How to find what is causing to crash the app

Tags: ios, multithreading, crash, watchdog

My App seeing crashes very rarely on some devices with this crash log, How to identify what is making iOS terminating the app due to extended time and watchdog issues is occurring.

I tried to understand and locate the issue reading these articles but somewhat not getting exactly to pin it.
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/analyzing-a-crash-report)

And this [What does 8badf00d mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773442/what-does-8badf00d-mean)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.someaudio.podcast>:2296 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 17.300 (user 17.300, system 0.000), 29% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 10.037, 17% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd521e7c 0x1bd4f8000 + 171644
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef241fc 0x18ef1f000 + 20988
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef23f90 0x18ef1f000 + 20368
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef32c08 0x18ef1f000 + 80904
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef32798 0x18ef1f000 + 79768
5   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001a4946d18 0x1a4940000 + 27928
6   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001a49474ac 0x1a4940000 + 29868
7   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001a49460b0 0x1a4940000 + 24752
8   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001a49468a0 0x1a4940000 + 26784
9   MyApp                           0x0000000105535148 0x104fac000 + 5804360
10  MyApp                           0x0000000105538ed4 0x104fac000 + 5820116
11  MyApp                           0x0000000105539614 0x104fac000 + 5821972
12  MyApp                           0x0000000105536fdc 0x104fac000 + 5812188
13  MyApp                           0x0000000105537e40 0x104fac000 + 5815872
14  MyApp                           0x0000000105359fc0 0x104fac000 + 3858368
15  UIKitCore                       0x0000000191d21e00 0x19115d000 + 12340736
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000019137f720 0x19115d000 + 2238240
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019137fb4c 0x19115d000 + 2239308
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000019137f388 0x19115d000 + 2237320
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001913878cc 0x19115d000 + 2271436
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001917f5e84 0x19115d000 + 6917764
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000191901268 0x19115d000 + 8012392
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001913875c4 0x19115d000 + 2270660
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001911af4ac 0x19115d000 + 337068
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001911ade2c 0x19115d000 + 331308
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001911af0d4 0x19115d000 + 336084
26  UIKitCore                       0x000000019181f994 0x19115d000 + 7088532
27  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e908eb8 0x19e8fe000 + 44728
28  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e9354f0 0x19e8fe000 + 226544
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e9176a4 0x19e8fe000 + 104100
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e93541c 0x19e8fe000 + 226332
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef2381c 0x18ef1f000 + 18460
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef2730c 0x18ef1f000 + 33548
33  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e95bfa0 0x19e8fe000 + 384928
34  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e95bc30 0x19e8fe000 + 384048
35  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e95c184 0x19e8fe000 + 385412
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2b0990 0x18f20d000 + 670096
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2b088c 0x18f20d000 + 669836
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2afb90 0x18f20d000 + 666512
39  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9b70 0x18f20d000 + 641904
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9308 0x18f20d000 + 639752
41  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a692c734 0x1a6929000 + 14132
42  UIKitCore                       0x0000000191d2775c 0x19115d000 + 12363612
43  UIKitCore                       0x0000000191d2cfcc 0x19115d000 + 12386252
44  MyApp                           0x0000000104ffb2a4 0x104fac000 + 324260
45  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018ef65cf8 0x18ef64000 + 7416

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc4fc 0x1bd4f8000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fb884 0x1bd4f8000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2afe58 0x18f20d000 + 667224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9cf8 0x18f20d000 + 642296
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9308 0x18f20d000 + 639752
5   Foundation                      0x0000000190598d8c 0x190590000 + 36236
6   Foundation                      0x0000000190598c58 0x190590000 + 35928
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000191ddc304 0x19115d000 + 13103876
8   Foundation                      0x000000019070a30c 0x190590000 + 1549068
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad744 0x1dafa3000 + 42820

Thread 3 name:  com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc4fc 0x1bd4f8000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fb884 0x1bd4f8000 + 14468
2   MyApp                           0x0000000105598a50 0x104fac000 + 6212176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc4fc 0x1bd4f8000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fb884 0x1bd4f8000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2afe58 0x18f20d000 + 667224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9cf8 0x18f20d000 + 642296
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9308 0x18f20d000 + 639752
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fb87b38 0x18f93c000 + 2407224
6   Foundation                      0x000000019070a30c 0x190590000 + 1549068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 5 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc4fc 0x1bd4f8000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fb884 0x1bd4f8000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2afe58 0x18f20d000 + 667224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9cf8 0x18f20d000 + 642296
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9308 0x18f20d000 + 639752
5   AudioSession                    0x0000000196d58f20 0x196d4c000 + 53024
6   AudioSession                    0x0000000196d5b0d8 0x196d4c000 + 61656
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc4fc 0x1bd4f8000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fb884 0x1bd4f8000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2afe58 0x18f20d000 + 667224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9cf8 0x18f20d000 + 642296
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2a9308 0x18f20d000 + 639752
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2aa3f4 0x18f20d000 + 644084
6   CoreMotion                      0x000000019a440c78 0x19a2f4000 + 1363064
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc550 0x1bd4f8000 + 17744
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef23e00 0x18ef1f000 + 19968
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef24410 0x18ef1f000 + 21520
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef34dbc 0x18ef1f000 + 89532
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad744 0x1dafa3000 + 42820

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bd4fc550 0x1bd4f8000 + 17744
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef23e00 0x18ef1f000 + 19968
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef24410 0x18ef1f000 + 21520
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef34dbc 0x18ef1f000 + 89532
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa4bfc 0x1dafa3000 + 7164
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad758 0x1dafa3000 + 42840

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad744 0x1dafa3000 + 42820

Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: mlq.MyApp.SynchronizedArray
Thread 11:
0   MyAppAPI                        0x00000001075a1448 0x107500000 + 660552
1   MyAppAPI                        0x00000001075eab18 0x107500000 + 961304
2   MyApp                           0x0000000105048fec 0x104fac000 + 643052
3   MyApp                           0x000000010553455c 0x104fac000 + 5801308
4   MyApp                           0x000000010525f5d0 0x104fac000 + 2831824
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef21a84 0x18ef1f000 + 10884
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef2381c 0x18ef1f000 + 18460
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef33e94 0x18ef1f000 + 85652
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef2bc70 0x18ef1f000 + 52336
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef2683c 0x18ef1f000 + 30780
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef34fe0 0x18ef1f000 + 90080
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ef357d8 0x18ef1f000 + 92120
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafa6768 0x1dafa3000 + 14184
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dafad74c 0x1dafa3000 + 42828

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x00000000ffffffff   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000286293f80   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000280924f40   x7: 0x0000000000000001
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000100  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x006000150000630d
   x12: 0x0000000200000003  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000000000000d7  x15: 0x00000001f19d3458
   x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x00000001f19d3458  x18: 0x000000010bef9ac0  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016ae51650  x21: 0x0000000001000001  x22: 0x00000000ffffffff  x23: 0x00000001a4947e30
   x24: 0x0000000280924f40  x25: 0x00000001f1a10658  x26: 0x0000000280245bf0  x27: 0x000000016ae51720
   x28: 0x00000001f22254c8   fp: 0x000000016ae51590   lr: 0x000000018ef241fc
    sp: 0x000000016ae51570   pc: 0x00000001bd521e7c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log to see where it crashed.  Look at what you are doing in `didFinishLaunching`. If this method takes too long you will get a watchdog crash.  You should perform the minimum amount of work in that method before returning.

Comment: My didFinishLauching is not making any extensive work, And the app never gets stuck on launch. It only gets stuck if the user backgrounds the app and reopen it.

Comment: Ok. You can eventually exhaust your background allocation too.  Start by symbolicating the crash log, but there may be nothing you can do if you are exceeding your background allocation

Comment: I am afraid to ask but can you help how to symbolize the crash log? As this is sent from a client device manually. Crashlytics is not reporting any crashes. Thanks.

Comment: You will need the .crash file as well as the dsyms from the build https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode